# Am I applying the formula of independence when there is dependence between the outcomes of the draws?

Tags: probability

Suppose an urn contains 1 red ball and 2 white balls. A person draws out balls, one at a
time and without replacement.

Let $X_i=1$, if the ith ball is red, and $0$ otherwise.

Then,

$$P(X_1=0, X_2=1, X_3=0)=(2/3)(1/2)(1)=(1/3).$$

I didn't understand how the joint distribution $P(X_1=0, X_2=1, X_3=0)$ can be written as multiplication $P(X_1=0)\times P(X_2=1)\times P(X_3=0)=(2/3)(1/2)(1)$ since they are not independent. We drew the balls without replacement.

Again,

$$P(X_1=1, X_2=0, X_3=0)=(1/3)(1)(1)=(1/3).$$
$$P(X_1=0, X_2=0, X_3=1)=(2/3)(1/2)(1)=(1/3).$$

From here, we can see that $P(X_i=1)$ will be the same for all $i = 1, 2, 3$.

But I see $P(X_1=1)=(1/3)$, but if the red ball is drawn in the 2nd draw, then $P(X_2=1)=(1/2)$, and if the red ball is drawn in the 3rd/last draw, then $P(X_3=1)=1.$

Then, how can it be that $P(X_i=1)$ will be the same for all $i = 1, 2, 3$?

Comment: Independence is not used in that expansion, just conditional probability.  The probability that the first is white and the second is red is the product of the conditional probability (second red conditioned on first white) times the probability that the first was white.

Comment: Note:  to get the result, you need not write it out this way.  A priori, each ball has an equal chance of being drawn second, so the probability that the unique red is drawn second is $\frac 13$.

Comment: It is not the same for all j, for example, j=0 for all X_i. I assume you meant probability that a given X_i = 1 is the same for all i

Comment: To add some math symbolism to what @lulu has said: e.g., in the first equality, $(2/3)(1/2)(1)$ is not $P(X_1=0)P(X_2=1)P(X_3=0)$. It is $P(X_1=0)P(X_2=1\mid X_1=0)P(X_3=0\mid X_1=0,X_2=1)$.